# How to Insert Information into a Database Using a Java Servlet

Tags: java

Help! I'm working on a class project and I have to insert information into a database using a Java Servlet...yes, it HAS to be a Java Servlet. I've got the code almost correct, but I'm getting illegal start of expression errors when I try to compile it.

Here is the code:

```
    //This servlet processes the user's registration and redirects them to the catalog.

// Load required libraries
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet{

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // JDBC driver name and database URL
      static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
      static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";

      //  Database credentials
      static final String USER = "user";
      static final String PASS = "";

      try{
         // Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

         // Execute SQL query
         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         sql = "INSERT INTO dvdsite VALUES username, password, email";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         // Clean-up environment
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         //finally block used to close resources
         try{
            if(stmt!=null)
               stmt.close();
         }catch(SQLException se2){
         }// nothing we can do
         try{
            if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
         }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
         }//end finally try
      } //end try
     }
     }
```

Can someone please help? I have been struggling with this for days!

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? A stacktrace?

Comment: static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static final declarations should be outside the method call - just in the class.

```
public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet{
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
      private static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
      private static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. That got read of two of the errors. I'm still getting errors on these two lines.

//  Database credentials
      static final String USER = "user";
      static final String PASS = "";

Comment: @TonySmith:- Just do the same thing for them too ie, take them outside the method call! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I tried that and I get: 1 error found:
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register.java  [line: 15]
Error: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register.java:15: ';' expected and it goes up to 12 errors. The message pops up on right after the IOException

Comment: @TonySmith:- You need to check the brackets. You must be missing any. Also check the ;

Answer (score 1):

1) I think this is not the proper way to write the insert query:-

```
sql = "INSERT username, password, email INTO dvdsite";
```

You may change it to like this:-

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dvdsite values(username, password, email)";
```

Assuming your `dvdsite`  table has just three columns else you need to specify the column names as well.

2) Also the `static final` declaration should be in the class ie, just make it outside the method.

```
public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet{

      private static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
      private static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dvdsite";
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String PASS = "";
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
```

3) As you commented that you are getting the error after changing everything. This is because you are missing the `semicolon ;` here:-

```
   throws ServletException, IOException;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several compilation errors:

1. static members cannot be defined within a method, it should be in the class
2. the connection and statement object are not declared

and finally you sql insert is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

**the issue in "{}"**

correct code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connectivity 

    {   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   // JDBC driver name and database URL
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS";

       //  Database credentials
       static final String USER = "username";
       static final String PASS = "password";

       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Connection conn = null;//create object of Connection and define it null
      try //try block
      {
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                        //print on console
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");      
                }
      catch(SQLException se) //catch block
      {
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch(Exception e) //catch block
      {
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally  //finally block
      {
      //finally block used to close resources
      try  //try block
      {
      if(conn!=null)//condition
      conn.close(); //close connection
      }
      catch(SQLException se)//Handle errors
      {
      se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
      }//end try
      System.out.println("Goodbye!"); //print on console
     }//end main
}
```

Comment: Can you specifically point which `{}` is the issue, instead of pasting whole snippet?